# python import works interactively but not from script

Tags: python, windows, python-module

*Disclaimer: I'm not a Windows expert, so this may be something idiosyncratic to Windows.*

I'm observing a situation where I can import a module in interactive mode but not when requested from a file.  Here is `foo.py` in its entirety:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyftdi
```

When I try to run this in Python 3.6.4, it fails:

```
E:\>py foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyftdi
ImportError: No module named pyftdi
```

...but when I import the module interactively, it succeeds:

```
E:\>py
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyftdi
>>>
```

(FWIW, I don't get an error when repeating this under Mac OS X.)

Any thoughts about what's going on?

Comment: By using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`, you're having the launcher search `PATH` for python.exe. Change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` or just `#!python3` to force the launcher to use the highest version of 3.x that's installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the version of python is different and has different modules installed. To fix this you can simply do `py -3.6 foo.py` instead of `py foo.py`.

Comment: Aha!  You're right: printing sys.version within foo.py shows v 2.7.14.  However, `>>> py3.6` gives me `py3.6 is not recognized as an internal or external command`, but that's a separate issue.  Checkmark is yours...

Answer (score -1):

**Working directory**

I had a situation where the script was importing from it's working directory and the shell was importing from the global libraries.